# Music using orchestra with a singer and a pop/rock/jazz song's style?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I wonder if there is a special name for the kind of music where there is an orchestra and a singer singing a pop, rock, or jazz song?

I've listened to some of them (but hardly with a pop or rock influence) such as [Hooverphonic - Mad About You (Live at Koningin Elisabethzaal 2012)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EA-MIYY1bg) (this song is maybe not the best example of what I'm looking for though).

So I wonder if you knew any such name or genre for artists doing that kind of music?

Comment: Why couldn't it be still called Rock (or Pop, or Jazz...)? The fact that there are orchestral instrument doesn't cancel the Rock genre, I suppose...

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. But I want to find artist making that kind of music, so I just asked if it could be categorized in a genre or not, and if someone knew anything similar.

Comment: ok. I'm not good in finding genres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different genres that use orchestration.  If it's jazz, we generally call it "big band," although there is also something called ["orchestral jazz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestral_jazz), as well as wide repertoire of jazz-influenced classical music. Similarly, there is an actual subgenre called "orchestral rock" (think Led Zeppelin's "Kashmir").

But this particular song is ["chamber pop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_pop), a style combining pop sensibilities with lush orchestral accompaniments.  It was pioneered by the Beatles (*Sgt Pepper*, "Yesterday") and the Beach Boys (*[Pet Sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0spkrwl9Qk&list=PLW79q83govkXJJBEnMnlvJ7B1b3xPosvO)*).  Controversial producer Phil Spector is also associated with the genesis of the style, for instance in his epic collaboration with Tina Turner, ["River Deep, Mountain High."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULw1RHHPv5g)

For more recent variations, you might compare singer [Chris Mills](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u375OJ1VTq4), pop composer [Ben Folds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9XEopGBH1c), who often books tours where he appears with local orchestras, and cult classic band XTC's [*Apple Venus 1.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgUuaiiRTas)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with Rock Orchestra for combo's like Scorpions, Metallica, Kiss and such that bring in an orchestra for a concert. If you have a better name for the genre let me know.

Comment: Did you find articles, discs examples that use this designation (links or quotes would be nice) or is this just your own opinion?